# How can I stop fresh downloads of our public windows phone8 App submitted through developer account?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, mobile-application, windows-phone-store

We have public windows phone 8 application in windows phone store. I want that new users should not be able to download the app via store but the app should run fine for existing users. Will the "Hide App in Store" option work? What is this "Hide App in Store" for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'hide app' will stop in appearing in searches. However, if someone shares the link it will still be downloadable by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

What `Hide App in Store` means is that, you'll be able to hide your app from searching from the `Store` using a `keyword` or something.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj619160(v=vs.105).aspx)